# tables question simple

Tags: html

http://jsfiddle.net/rcZZb/7/

I want to put 2 boxes of text side by side below the top 2 images. When I try to add 2 Td's it doesn't work. I tried seting the width on the td but that didn't work. I wanted my 2 boxes of text to be different sizes but to fit still within the top table width.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into using [colspan*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp). I applied `colspan="2"` to your `<td>`'s which was solo inside their respective `<tr>`s.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/rcZZb/11/

```
--------------------------
|  this spans 2 columns  |
--------------------------
|   1 column | 1 column  |
--------------------------
```

Comment: But that pushes the 2nd image to the right. I want it to stay one image at the top then then the other image below it. Then below that 2 boxes of text side by side.

Comment: Nice. So by default is colspan set to 1. Not sure why you would set it on the image td's when its the text boxes that I want to be in 2 columns. Also how would I set the width of each td that has text inside

Comment: Well, think about what colspan is = "columns to span". You need to apply it to the images' `<td>`s because they each span two columns. Look at the diagram in my answer. You should actually get away from using tables completely. It's a deprecated way to design sites. Look into divs and css.

Comment: Yea I don't use them usually that's why I'm asking such stupid questions here. Its for an emailer and alot of email blasts don't support div's. How would I set the width of the td when I try to say <td width="200"> it doesn't work.

Comment: Tables are tabular, meaning all the `<td>`s combined widths need to add up to the width of the table.

Comment: I got the width to work. Thanks for updating the fiddle but unfortunately floats don't work in some emailers.

Comment: Ah ok - well glad I could help you out bro :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly you need to add `colspan="2"` to your `td` of your images. See: http://jsfiddle.net/rcZZb/10/

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rcZZb/12/

You need to add `colspan="2"` to images' TDs.